# <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile 'open' failed too many open files

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

the app is working fine. but if you play 15-20 levels, i get this error

> ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed
>   '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3420459D-280A-4B0E-84D0-0729B8264014/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F74E13D9-5466-4A82-91E9-900516E0219E/xyxy/frontImage.png'

error = 24 (Too many open files)

with all images in my app.

ARC is on.

this is a snippet of my view:

```
@interface CardView()

@property (nonatomic) UIImage *frontImage;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backImage;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *whiteImage;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *flashImage;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImage1;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImage2;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImage3;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImage1b;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImage2b;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImage3b;

@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImageCircle1;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImageCircle2;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *backMultiGameImageCircle3;

@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *circlePlayer;

@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer;

@property (nonatomic) GameModel *gameModel;

@end

@implementation CardView


-(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame andPosition: (NSInteger)pos andValue: (NSInteger)value {
self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
if (self) {

    // IMAGE
    self.frontImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"DOT_Game_Highlighted.png"]];
    self.backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_Black.png"];

    self.backMultiGameImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_1.png"];
    self.backMultiGameImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_2.png"];
    self.backMultiGameImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_3.png"];

    self.backMultiGameImage1b = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_1B.png"];
    self.backMultiGameImage2b = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_2B.png"];
    self.backMultiGameImage3b = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_3B.png"];

    self.backMultiGameImageCircle1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_1_1.png"];
    self.backMultiGameImageCircle2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_1_2.png"];
    self.backMultiGameImageCircle3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_2_1.png"];

return self;
}
```

I call this method with:

```
-(void) generateCardsForLevel1 {

    CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPosition:i andValue:value];
}
```

for each level i have this method. (generateCardsForLevel2, generateCardsForLevel3...)

I thought, ARC release my images automatically? what can i do?

is it possible to declare the images once in my app delegate, so that he load the images only once?

UPDATE: I tried now to add to each method @autoreleasepool, and at the end of my current VC to nil all out. but theres no change...